# Conflicting rules in AWS subnet NACL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I  am learning about AWS NACL . I am trying to SSH to AWS EC2 instance using VPN . I get the following error

ssh  -i amazon-linux-key.pem ec2-user@10.250.92.154
ssh: connect to host 10.250.92.154 port 22: Resource temporarily unavailable

But ping 10.250.92.154 is working with 0% packet loss

Subnet where I have created Ec2 instance has following Inbound and outbound rules :

```
80  All traffic All All 10.250.92.0/23   Allow
85  All traffic All All 10.250.0.0/16    Deny
100 All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0    Allow
*   All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0    Deny
```

Rule 80 and 85 seems conflicting to me . I assume this is causing the issue . Any thoughts on this will be appreciated

Comment: Why do you modify NACLS? Its better  to use default ones, and just use Security Groups to limit access to your instance. Have you tried that? Does ssh work with default NACLS?

Comment: This setup has been done  by the IT team . I am trying to understand why I am not able to do SSh to the Ec2 instance may be something wrongly setup in NACL

Answer (score 2):

NACL rules are **evaluated in order**. The first rule to be 'satisfied' is used.

- `10.270.92.0/23` is an **incorrect CIDR**. I presume you meant `10.250.92.0/23`, which is referenced in the error message
- `10.250.92.0/23` goes from `10.250.92.0` to `10.250.93.255`
- `10.250.93.0/16` goes from `10.250.0.0` to `10.250.255.255`

Therefore, if you are connecting to an EC2 instance at `10.250.92.154` and you are connecting from outside of the subnet (which means the NACL will be used), it will work as follows:

- If coming from `10.250.92.0` to `10.250.93.255`: **Allowed**
- Otherwise, if coming from `10.250.0.0` to `10.250.255.255`: **Denied**
- Otherwise: **Allowed**

Comment: Thanks John for explaining this . That means based on the first rule which allows traffic , I should be able to connect to EC2 instance vis SSH .But I am not able to connect to SHH . Any other things which I can check ?

Comment: What IP address are you connecting FROM and what IP address are you connecting TO? Also, what is the Security Group associated with the target EC2 instance? Also, please correct your question to show the correct IP addresses (eg without `270`).

Comment: John I have updated my question

Comment: What IP address are you connecting FROM and what IP address are you connecting TO? Also, what is the Security Group associated with the target EC2 instance?